# Force my custom CSS style to the static folders and files that I'm getting from my express js server

Tags: css, node.js, express

I'm serving my static Linux files and folders using Express (as a server). There's no problem with my code. Still for the sake of clarification, I'm providing the code

```
const express = require('express');
var serveIndex = require('serve-index');
const app = express();


var __dirname = "/media/user/"

app.use('/data', serveIndex(__dirname));
app.use ("/data", express.static(__dirname))

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log ("server listening at port 3000")
})
```

My actual problem is, I want to force my custom CSS styles (like changing font color, size of files & folders etc) to the display I'm getting upon visiting the localhost:300/data URL. This is the response I'm getting from express server

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serve-index` module [has a way of passing path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-index#stylesheet) to custom stylesheet, try using `stylesheet` option when initializing it, like this:

```
app.use('/data', serveIndex(__dirname, { stylesheet: '/path/to/stylesheet/' }));
```